# The RecyclerView is not showing in the main activity

Tags: android-studio

I can't find why. Help, please.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tUpk9aR-5XOSxt6PMAmYu7ZEfx_w8FUH

Comment: please add more information about your issue

Comment: I am trying to do a todo list app, so I created a recyclerView for the list but it's not showing up in the main activity.

Comment: The app is being built correctly and no errors.